# Open file in universal-newline mode when using pkg_resources?

Tags: python, csv, pkg-resources

I am processing a CSV file and have the following working code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rU'), dialect='excel')
header = reader.next()
```

However, to be compatible with elsewhere in the codebase, I need to use a file object using `pkg_resources.resource_stream`, as follows:

```
fileobj = pkg_resources.resource_stream('foo', 'tests/bar.csv')
reader = csv.reader(fileobj, dialect='excel')
header = reader.next()
```

(I'm simplifying here - basically the `csv.reader` code is in a function over which I don't have control, and it expects a `fileobj`.)

This throws the following error.

```
Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Any idea how I can use universal-newline mode with my `fileobj`? I can't see anything about this in the `pkg_resources` documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If the stream always has an fd (e.g. because it's a normal opened file on the filesystem), you can use `os.fdopen(fileobj.fileno(), 'rU')` to open it with the right mode.